# I am getting an error while installing a module named fblogin block in prestashop 1.7.8.0

Tags: php, error-handling, module, prestashop-1.7

I am using **Prestashop 1.7.8.0** and I am getting an error while installing a module named **fbloginblock** and it is not getting solved by increasing **post_max_size** in **Php.ini** file and I also tried with putting it directly on ftp but not getting perfect solution. can any please help me ??[this is the error it is showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKdZr.png)

Comment: have you tried to increase upload_max_filesize too?

Comment: have you restarted your web server after increasing post_max_size ?